# Angular 4 with authentication from backend

Tags: angular, drupal-8

One of the backend developer has developed drupal website and once any use logs in from the drupal end he will be redirected to Angular4 dashboard and here at the Angular4 part i need to authenticate the user to access the dashboard only if the user is a authenticated user. Here i dont have any login part to allow the user to login but i need to manipulate the user as a logged in user. So in Angular how to achieve this? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: are both the sites hosted on the same URL?

Comment: Hi! Please see [ask] and how to create a [mcve]. Try something, write some code, and come back with a _specific problem_.

Comment: @Parijat Purohit: yes both on same url

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if the entire entire site shares the same URL, you manage the sessions using a cookie variable.

Generally, ORMs manage the sessions internally but as you said that you have separate applications running under the same URL, you'll have to always ask this database for the User information through the exposed API.

Sadly, you cannot do authentication purely on the front-end as javascript can be easily disabled and sessions are not fool-proof. What you can actually go forward with is something which the industry generally follows: OAuth. You can read more about it [here](https://oauth.net/2/).

Oauth enables you to have a centralized authorization system and acts as a standard for all login authorizations. Every authentication call, even from your old application is then actually forwarded to the OAuth server which validates and sens you back the User Data. While there are many ways to do it, you can obviously go through some already implemented examples to get a gist of how it is actually done. [Digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2) actually provides a very good insight of how OAuth works.

As I mentioned, you can always have the cookie shared among your previous application which can act as the authorization key for your API which fetches user data and don't need a seperate OAuth server altogether, but even in this case, you'll need to have an API exposed to fetch user data based upon the cookie's session variable.